# Combining Multiple Solutions into one Solution in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution file that has the following example projects:
SharedLibrary
NonSharedLibrary
WebProject
WebProject.Install

Then another solution file that has the following example projects:
SharedLibrary
WindowsServiceProject
WindowsServiceProject.Install

Currently I open both in two separate instances of VS2010. The share library is the same in both but shared through my source control.
Is there an easy way to create another Solution file that when opened, opens all necessary projects for both. Then when testing, etc. you just change your startup project.

All the while maintaining the ability to open the old solutions if you want to just work on one of them.

Has any one does this before and/or know of a good methodology?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio solutions are basically containers that group projects together. You can reuse the same projects in multiple solutions. A common way of handling this is to have one solution that contains **all** of your projects. Then create additional solutions that only load **some** of the projects. For example, you might make one solution for UI developers that only loads the projects they need while other developers might not care about the UI but need the windows service.

Each developer can set their own startup project which is stored in their local .suo file.

If you have multiple solutions open simultaneously and you change one project then you'll get the reload message in the other instance since they are shared.

Comment: So I guess maybe source control is my issue. The full situation is that we have 4 large solutions, each that share about 80% of their projects.
I guess i could share EVERY project in source control to a new directory, then create a solution that opens all of them.
Does that seem like the ticket?

Comment: What are you using for source control? I generally use SVN or TFS and prefer to have the entire tree sync'd local and then open just the solution that I care about at the time. That way all source is available but I don't have to see it all at once in Visual Studio.

Comment: We use sourcegear vault(not a fan by the way).
We are running into the opposite issue. Our developers are consistently having to have 3 or 4 instances of VS open.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 C++ seems to break this pattern.  With VS2010 a project compiled from one solution is considered to be in an invalid state when build is hit on another solution that shares that project.  This leads to constant rebuilding if you switch between solutions.  Before VS2010 this worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just create a new (or several) empty solutions right next to your existing one and then just add to it the projects you want to see there (Add Existing project)